# need help in creating scss function to return string

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I need to include the module import in many places, so i wanted to create mixin or function in scss.

> on my mixin.scss

```
 @function import-modules($import,$grid){
      @return $import +' modules/modulename_'+$grid ;
  }
```

> in main.scss where i want to import, i have

```
import-modules (@import,1024);
```

but it throws me error. How can I create a function to return import statement?

The error I get :Invalid CSS after "import-modules": expected "{", was "('@import',1024);")

Thanks for your answer, I modified and tried it this way:

```
$modulesList: 'modules/header/header_', 
'modules/news/news_', 
'modules/footer/footer_', 
'modules/follow_us/follow_us_', 
'modules/ads/ads_', 
'modules/newsletter/newsletter_', 
'modules/comments/comments_';

@function import-modules($grid){
    @each $module in $modulesList{
                @return $module+$grid;
                }

}
@import url(import-modules(1024));
```

In css, I see:
  @import url("modules/header/header_1024");

Answer (score 1):

Sass doesn't execute arbitrary strings.  If you want to import a file, you have to use the `@import` directive.

```
@function import-modules($grid){
    @return 'modules/modulename_#{$grid}';
}

@import url(import-modules(1024));
```

However...

> Imports may contain #{} interpolation, but only with certain restrictions. It’s not possible to dynamically import a Sass file based on a variable; interpolation is only for CSS imports. As such, it only works with url() imports.

Source: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: Please check the modified comment. Basically, it stopped importing and started printing the import statement.